# sequence equality in boost mpl pop_back

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming

I'm reading [David Abrahams's C++ Template Metaprogramming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321227255), on ch 5.6 Sequence Equality he says:

> It's important, particularly when handling computed results, not to
>   fall into the trap of relying on sequence type identity. For example,
>   you should not expect the following assertion to pass:
>
> ```
> BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((      // error
>   boost::is_same<
>       mpl::pop_back<mpl::vector<int, short> >::type
>     , mpl::vector<int>
>   >::value
> ));
> ```
>
> For most purposes, the two types being compared above will act the same, and most of the time you'll never notice a difference. That
>   said, the result of using mpl::pop_back on a specialization of
>   mpl::vector will not be another specialization of mpl::vector!
>
> As you
>   saw in our exploration of dimensional analysis in Chapter 3, a
>   function template that can only be called with two identical types is
>   likely not to work as expected if those types are sequences. The same
>   goes for a class template partial specialization that matches only
>   when two type arguments are identical.
>
> The correct way to check for
>   sequence equality is always to use the equal algorithm, as follows:
>
> ```
> BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((        // OK
>   mpl::equal<
>       mpl::pop_back<mpl::vector<int, short> >::type
>     , mpl::vector<int>
>   >::value
> ));
> ```

I don't understand here: "That said, the result of using mpl::pop_back on a specialization of mpl::vector will not be another specialization of mpl::vector", then what is the result of `mpl::popback` here?

[Boost manual on pop_back](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/pop-back.html) says the Return type is "Back Extensible Sequence", isn't `mpl::vector` a back extensible sequence?

Answer (score 0):

It will be a constructed sequence type of some kind, You can look at the pop_back_impl for vector in